# Blown-out speaker ffmpeg sound effect

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, wav, audio-player

I was wondering how to do the blown-out speaker effect using ffmpeg where the audio just sounds completely destroyed.

I've tried a bunch of combinations of different commands on ffmpeg and the closest I've gotten is the following (where I use the superequalizer and then make the volume super high):

```
import ffmpeg
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('shark.wav')
    .filter("superequalizer", 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)
    .filter("volume", 10)
    .output('output_speaker.wav')
    .run()
)
```

I'm using a python wrapper but here's the command line equivalent:

```
ffmpeg -i shark.wav -af "superequalizer=1b=20:2b=20:3b=20:4b=20:5b=20:6b=20:7b=20:8b=20:9b=20:10b=20:11b=20:12b=20:13b=20:14b=20:15b=20:16b=20:17b=20:18b=20,volume=10" output_speaker.wav
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't do anything for files that aren't already super loud (such as recorded audio) and most of the time the audio actually just ends up clipping and then being super soft.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think you want a bitcrusher with the bit reduction set as high as possible. for instance:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af acrusher=.1:1:64:0:log output.wav
```

ffmpeg documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrusher

Comment: I'm finding some success combining this with `bass`, `dcshift`, and `crystalizer`.